# what is the underling of treasury bond future contracts? and what determine/drives bond future's theoretical/market prices?

Tags: fixed-income, bond, bond-futures

Am I right that the underlying is a basket of deliverable bonds? 
If this is the case, how is the bond future prices actually determined? 
If there was only one bond in the deliverable set, the bond future price's theoretical price can be easily determined by non arbitrage theory. 
But if the underlying is a basket of bonds, how is its theoretical value being determined ?
And how about its actual market price? is it purely determined by demand and supply ?

Comment: There are many questions here, and I believe they're mostly answered already, such as https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18018/pricing-treasury-futures/18043, https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/32624/price-of-bond-future-given-a-specific-interest-rate/32630, etc. I recommend that you review these first and come back with more targeted questions so that we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Please carefully read the following link, which shall answer all of your questions

http://www.cmegroup.com/content/dam/cmegroup/rulebook/CBOT/V/18/18.pdf